# Free calloc in shared library using ctypes

Tags: python, c, memory-management, ctypes, calloc

I have this struct:

```
struct result {
    int position;
    int *taken;
};

struct result get_result(int pos, int take[]){
    struct result res;
    res.position = pos;
    res.taken = take;
    return res;
}
```

Which I call in a function:

```
struct result get_taken_values(){
    //some code
    int position = 0;
    int* chosen = calloc(9, sizeof(int));     
    //some more code
    struct result res;
    res.position = position;
    res.taken = chosen;
    return res;
}
```

If I were to use this in main, I would simply call `free(res.taken) in the end`.

But I'm making this into a shared library using:

```
gcc -fPIC -c get_taken_values.c
ld -shared -soname libtest.so.1 -o my_library.so -lc get_taken_values.o
```

I'll be using this library in Python using ctypes.

Do I need to free the calloc, if so how do I do it?

Comment: Since the array is fixed size, why not simply define `int taken[9]` in the struct? Then you don't need `calloc` and `free`. ctypes handles `ctypes.Structure` subclasses set in `restype`, but you could also allocate the struct in Python and pass it in by reference for the function to modify.

Comment: you could define a function `free_taken_values()` that does the necessary cleanup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you need a variable sized array for `taken`, then you can create a `ctypes.Structure`, give it a `__del__` method that will call `free`. You can call `free` by loading `libc`. `__del__` is called after the last reference to an object falls out of scope. Using `__del__` can cause problems if your objects contain circular references as python will not know which objects to call `__del__` on first (so it doesn't, it just keeps the objects hanging around in memory).

```
from ctypes import Structure, c_int, POINTER, CDLL
from ctypes.util import find_library

__all__ = ["get_taken_values", "Result"]

libc = CDLL(find_library("c"))
libmy_library = CDLL("./my_library.so")

class Result(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("position", c_int),
        ("taken", POINTER(c_int)),
        ("size", c_int)
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return "result(position={}, taken={})".format(
            self.position, self.taken[:self.size])

    def __del__(self):
        libc.free(self.taken)

get_taken_values = libmy_library.get_taken_values
get_taken_values.argtypes = ()
get_taken_values.restype = Result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = get_taken_values()
    print("position is {} and value at position is {}".format(
        result.position, result.taken[result.position]))
    print(result)
```

This makes the assumption that the instance of the python `Result` is the owner of the memory. Also, if `taken` really is variable sized then you will need to include the size member in your struct that `Result` references. If `taken` is a fixed size then you can just declare taken as an array in the struct, forget about using free, and use `c_int * 9` rather than `POINTER(c_int)` when declaring the type of `taken` in python.

Comment: @eryksun I only really have experience with glibc and linux. It might be better to add the edits relevant to a microsoft runtime to the answer yourself.

Comment: @eryksun Ah, I see now.

Comment: Tried your approach, it works 'kinda', in C it gives me this: `position: 69, taken[0]: 3, taken[1]: 9`, while python gives me result(position=69, moves=[5, -1]). The  POINTER(c_int) is turning into a c_long, instead it should be an array of ints.

Comment: Without seeing more of your code I couldn't possibly comment on what's gone wrong.

Comment: If `c_long` is 32-bit on a platform, it gets used for `c_int` as well. On Windows a `long` is always 32-bit, even in a 64-bit process. Most other 64-bit platforms use a 64-bit `long`. But I don't know why it has the wrong value. Compare the actual pointer address in C vs Python. Use `addressof(result.taken.contents)`.